# Oracle/SQL - Finding records with one value excluding by similar record

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay let me do a better job explaining this.  Assume I have a person column and a type column.  The same person could be in the table multiple times, but with different types.  I want all the people who have a specified type UNLESS they are listed with other types.

So given this data

```
Person  Type
--------------
Bob     S
Sue     S
Bob     O
Tom     S
Frank   S
Frank   R
```

I want to see Persons who have the Type S, but are also not listed with either Type O or R.  So my query should return

```
Person  Type
--------------
Sue     S
Tom     S
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
SELECT person
FROM table
GROUP BY person
HAVING MIN(type) = 'S' AND MAX(type) = 'S'
```

However if you have multiple records for the same person and type 'S', then this will remove those duplicates

Comment: The OP has already stated that the same person can be present in the table multiple times with different types only, so no need to worry about that. Anyway, this is roughly the approach I was about to post as my answer until I saw your solution. (Only in mine I was going to use a slightly different condition, something like `HAVING MAX(type) = 'S' AND COUNT(*) = 1`.) Thanks (+1) for relieving me of the job. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select person, type
    from myTable
    where type = 'S'
        and person NOT IN (
            select person
                from myTable
                where type in ('O', 'R')
        )
```

Comment: I believe your 'type NOT IN' should be 'person NOT IN'.  I actually have this working, but have always been told 'IN' used in this manner is inefficient so I was trying to see if there was a more effective way of doing this.  Thanks though!

Comment: Ah, fixed. Sorry about that. :-) Thanks! If you want to see how efficient/inefficient it is, download the Oracle SQL Developer tool from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html and use the Query Plan to check the cost of each version you try. It's not a perfect test, but it gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: This works if you have a known set of types. You would want to change the where clause of the NOT IN query to "type != 'S'" to get a generic result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select distinct Person, Type
from table
where (Person, type) in
  (select distinct Person, Type
   from table
   having count(*) = 1)
```

Added distincts to handle your case.

Comment: I looked at something like that, but was concerned about the possibility of a Person being in the table multiple times with Type 'S' in which case I want them returned.

Answer (score 0):

As an option to the NOT IN syntax, an outer join could handle that too

```
select t1.person, t1.type    
from   person_Type t1, person_type t2
where  t1.person = t2.person(+)
and    t1.type != t2.type(+)
and    t1.type = 'S'
and    t2.type is null;
```

Or, in response to the comment - for those who prefer the ANSI syntax...

```
select t1.person, t1.type
from  person_type t1
left outer join person_type t2
on  t2.person = t1.person
and t2.type != t1.type
where t1.type = 'S'
and t2.type is null;
```

Comment: Personally, I think "from t1, t2" is eeeeevil, and always use the JOIN syntax. :-) It clarifies which conditions are filters and which are joins, and makes it easier to maintain down the road.

Comment: I agree and generally use ANSI syntax too, but find many people are so used to Oracle syntax that they balk at it. But I'll add the ANSI version in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT person, ptype FROM persons p1 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ptype ) 
FROM persons p2 
WHERE p2.person = p1.person) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT  person, type 
FROM      MyTable   t1 
WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT  type ) 
        FROM @MyTable t2 
        WHERE t2.person = t1.person 
        AND  t1.Type='s'
        ) = 1
GROUP BY person, type
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Gary's option for performance reasons, but a simpler method is:

```
SELECT Person FROM mytable WHERE Type = 'S'
MINUS
SELECT Person FROM mytable WHERE Type IN ('O','R');
```