# Oracle/SQL - Finding records with one value excluding nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question very similar to another question but I can't quite figure it out.  Here is the link to the original question:[Oracle/SQL - Finding records with one value excluding by similar record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169884/oracle-sql-finding-records-with-one-value-excluding-by-similar-record)

So similar to that problem, I have records that will either have a 1 or null.  the same records can be a combination of 1 or null and in those instances, I want to exclude the record altogether.  For example:

```
    Person  Type
    --------------
    Bob     1
    Sue     1
    Bob     null
    Tom     1
    Frank   1
    Frank   null
    Fred    null
```

I want the following returned:

```
    Person  Type
    --------------
    Sue     1
    Tom     1
```

Any direction on this would be very much appreciated.  I dont have much time to solve this so even speaking conceptually will help!

The closest I came was

```
    select person from table
    where type = 'S'
    MINUS
    select person from table
    where type is null
```

But of course that doesnt work.

I can write a function if that is the only way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select person, type from table
where type = '1'
and person not in (select person from table where type is null)
```

Comment: My real table has way too many records for an IN stmt to work.  but thank you.

Also, the first part would select Sue and Tom but the "IS NULL" part would not

Comment: @RyanNalls there is no such thing as "too many rows for an IN statement". A `not exists` _might_ be faster though. But you do want (only) Tom and Sue returned which is exactly what that statement does.

Comment: The second part not selecting Sue and Tom is the whole point as it's a NOT IN, so by Sue and Tom not being returned by the sub query it will ensure that they are returned by the main query.  I notice in your MINUS query that in the first part you say where type = 'S' - is this a typo?

Comment: Both are close together as long as you don't have an index on `person`. Once you have it `not exists` will most likely perform better. See execution plans of this Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/819a1/1

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Mark's `NOT IN` approach, this can also be written as a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
select p1.person
from person p1
where p1.type = 1
and not exists (select 1 
                from person p2
                where p1.person = p2.person
                and p2.type is null)
order by p1.person;
```

It essentially says: get me every person where type is 1 but where there is no other row for this person where the type is null.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7623c/4

Answer (score 1):

You can readily do this with analytic functions, and these often offer very good performance:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             sum(case when type is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by person) as Nullcnt
      from person p
     ) p
where nullcnt = 0;
```

Comment: Very nice! The solutions in the other answers (`NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `MINUS`) are pretty much equivalent, because they require an ANTI-JOIN (possibly scanning the `Person` table twice) which can be avoided with the analytic function / windowing combination.